# Getting Rethinkdb index metadata

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I'd like to obtain metadata about an index on a Rethinkdb table, such as

- what expression is used for arbitrary indexes
- what fields are used for compound indexes
- whether the index is multi or not

How can I get this information through the admin interface?
Through the Python API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately at this point you can't get any of this information. It's something that's planned as an addition to ReQL but hasn't been added yet.

If this issue is important to you I'd recommend opening an issue here: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb that's the best way to influence development direction.